# Nodejs How to make request object available globally in all files

Tags: node.js, express

I have a usecase where I need the request object available globally.

Let's consider this Case

server.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const seq = require('sequelize');

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
seq.Book.create({                // Book is the name of table
name:request.body.name,
account_id:request.auth.account_id
});
return res.send();
})
```

hooks/book.js

```
const afterCreate = (book)=>{   // this fun will be called automatically after creating the Book 
                                //   record
seq.Log.create({                // Log is the name of table
bookId:book.id,
account_id:book.account_id,
user_id:global.request.session.user.id    // I want request object availble here
})
}
```

I have lot of code like this in my application where I can't pass the userId to every function

Is there anyway I can make the request object available globally accessible everywhere in the code ?

Any help would be thankfull.

Comment: Why you can't just pass it on to all that need it. Global variables are really a last resort.

Comment: @Alejandro That is huge task for me. I know if there is no solution that is the only thing I have to do. But I am looking for some alternative and easy solution

Comment: Using global for a user identifier is a very very bad idea. The ID should be linked to a request context. What happens if you get multiple concurrent requests from different users? You will not know which global user id is linked to what request/ session.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this we can use async_hooks in nodejs

Please read this for more information :-  https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/the-power-of-async-hooks-in-node-js-8a2a84238acb

Comment: But there are some serious memory probelms with this. one alternative is using request-context npm package which uses domains